# How many different ways can $ 8 $ identical pens be distributed among $ 3 $ children if each child gets at least $ 2 $ pens and no more than $ 4 $?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I know the basic set up of this problem. Because each child gets at least two but no more than 4 pens for each child there is a factor equal to:

$$(x^2+x^3+x^4)^3$$ Note that I included it raised to the third power because there are three children. Now I have to find $x^8$. The question is how do I do that given this information?

Comment: Factor out $(x^2)^3$ ?

Comment: Give each kid $2$ pens. There are $2$ left over, so we are distributing $2$ pens between $3$ kids. The no more than $4$ condition is automatically satisfied.

Comment: Have you tried expanding the generating polynomial?  What is the coefficient of $x^8$?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that *André Nicolas*'s suggestion of giving what is surely needed first is exactly the same as *Alexey Burdin*'s suggestion of factoring out $(x^2)^3$. And *André*'s method should also allow you to see that the problem reduces to a much simpler one which has a standard easy solution by placing 2 dividers between the pens, since it is from the start impossible for any child to get more than 4. In general, one would use the inclusion-exclusion principle if the upper bounds are still there after getting rid of the lower bounds.